# Updated Push certificate and Apple Push Notification doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, apple-push-notifications

An iPhone app that used to work in development and production had its Push certificate expire.  I created a new certificate and have not been able to get Push Notifications working again in development.  ]

```
 1)  I created a new development_cert.p12 and used openssl to create a new pem file:
      openssl pkcs12 -in development_cert.p12 -out apple_push_notification_development.pem -nodes -clcerts
 2)  I created new provisioning profiles for development 
 3)  I turned off and on notifications on my device
```

**Update 1 -** Production Push Notifications work with the new certificate, but Development Push Notifications aren't working with the new certificate.

Any ideas why Development Push Notifications aren't working?

Answer (score 0):

Did you build your app with the development provisioning profile and install the updated app on your device? If not, your phone probably still works with the production APNS environment.

If you installed the app, did you register for push notifications and get a development device token?

Finally, if you got a development device token and sent it to your server, are you sure you used the development device token when trying to push a notification to your device? Are you sure you used the development certificate and connected to the sandbox APNS server?